# Eclipse get the active build configuration Programaticly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I develop an Eclipse plugin, where I need the information, which build configuration is currently active.

[build configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibYCt.png)

I have 4 pre-defined Build configurations which you can see in the Screenshot and I need to get the name of the active one and also the name of the active Project.

Something like that.

```
String activeBuild = getActiveBuild();
```

I didn't find any solution at the Internet, so does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by _"pre-defined Build configurations"_? Build configuration to build what? Perhaps you can provide a link to the documentation of what you are talking about. I have no clue to what the way too cropped screenshot belongs to.

Comment: I just need to get the name of the active build configuration programaticly

Comment: What build configurations are you talking about? Maybe a C/C++ build configuration?

Comment: The Picture shows 4 build configurations, I just need to know which of them is active and yes C/c++

Comment: I don't know much about CDT, but it looks you first have to get an `ICProjectDescription` of the project and then you can call `getActiveConfiguration()`, see e.g. CDT source code here: https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/blob/08693047c5235f3c17ec080dfa46efef226bc16d/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/ui/actions/BuildActiveConfigMenuAction.java#L136-L139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get your `IProject` instance as a reference called `project`, then do the following to obtain the configuration...

```
ICProjectDescription desc = CCorePlugin.getDefault().getProjectDescription(project, true);
ICConfigurationDescription cfgDescription = desc.getActiveConfiguration();
IConfiguration configuration = ManagedBuildManager.getConfigurationForDescription(cfgDescription);

// grab what you need from the configuration instance
```